# ReactJS Sending props to style doesnt work

Tags: reactjs

I have unusual problem , im sending props style to component from app.js .

```
full={('pic_full.webp')}
```

and getting it at :

```
style={{background: `url(${require('../../images/template/' + this.props.full)}) no-repeat center center;`}}
```

I have to use require as i cant import it , its a dynamic picture.

What happens is : Style doesnt render in inspect element and when i console log the path, its correct...

Very unusal problem.

Thanks infront

Comment: Why you are using `require`? Is that React Native?

Comment: No its reactjs, pictures are dinamic.

Answer (score 0):

Ok looks like i had to remove ; as i was copying from inspect element.

Spent whole day on this, i hope someone who google for issue find this answer and logic suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Make it as `full='pic_full.webp'`

change this to

```
style={{'background': `url(${require('../../images/template/' + this.props.full)}) no-repeat center center;`}}
```